# Thingsboard performance tests

Tags: spring, thingsboard

I try to execute the thingsboard performance test 
[Thingsboard performance tests](https://github.com/thingsboard/performance-tests)

```
$ sudo docker run -it --env-file .env --name tb-perf-test thingsboard/tb-performance-test
```

but I get this result, anyone can help, please

> Starting ThingsBoard Performance Tests...
>   16:57:11,071 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
>   16:57:11,071 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
>   16:57:11,071 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/usr/share/tb-performance-tests/conf/logback.xml]
>   16:57:11,085 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
>   16:57:11,085 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/usr/share/tb-performance-tests/conf/logback.xml]
>   16:57:11,085 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/usr/share/tb-performance-tests/bin/tb-performance-tests.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/logback.xml]
>   16:57:11,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
>   16:57:11,579 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
>   16:57:11,588 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
>   16:57:11,692 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
>   16:57:11,692 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
>   16:57:11,692 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
>   16:57:11,693 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.thingsboard] to INFO
>   16:57:11,693 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
>   16:57:11,693 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
>   16:57:11,694 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
>   16:57:11,708 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5387f9e0 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   16:57:21.391 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testExecutor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deviceAPITest'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceMqttAPITest': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using port 9090, while your deployment uses 8080.